# How to mock DynamoDB in AWS Lambda using Java?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, junit, amazon-dynamodb, mockito

I have a DynamoDB connection in AWS Lambda and I try to get an item from a table by key.
The code is like this

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.GetItemEnhancedRequest;
...


public class FooLambda implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>{
@Override
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, Context context){
try {

...

DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.create();
DynamoDbTable<FooEntity> fooTable = enhancedClient.table("foo_table", TableSchema.fromBean(FooEntity.class));
Key fooKey = Key.builder()
.partitionValue("foo_ket")
.build();
FooEntity fooItem = fooTable.getItem(GetItemEnhancedRequest.builder().key(fooKey).build());        
String barValue = fooItem.getBar();

...

} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

How do I mock this part of code in the unit test? I tried the following but it did not work

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

// prepare mocking
DynamoDbTable<fooEntity> dynamoDbTable = mock(DynamoDbTable.class);
when(dynamoDbClient.table("foo_table", TableSchema.fromBean(FooEntity.class))).thenReturn(dynamoDbTable);
FooEntity fooItem = mock(FooEntity.class);
when(dynamoDbTable.getItem(any(GetItemEnhancedRequest.class))).thenReturn(fooItem);

// run test
APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent apiGatewayProxyResponseEvent = handler.handleRequest(input, context);
```

Then error I got is

```
The security token included in the request is expired (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 03XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

which means I have not mocked the DynamoDB connection part successfully. How can I do it?

Comment: How did you mock dynamoDbClient? It would be nice if you'll add remaining code for test class. Maybe issue is happening in attempt to create dynamoDbClient.

Comment: It's usually a [bad practice to mock types you don't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own). You can use a [fake](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) class or do an integration test using something like [LocalStack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/dynamodb/) to spin up a fake implementation of dynamodb.